# Catch unevaluated integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, debugging

I have a lot of integrals to evaluate. So, I do that in loops. Most of the integrals are solved with no problems and I enjoy it. But some of the integrals generate error messages like Infinity::indet or Integrate::idiv and I was able to find the integrals causing the errors (i.e. loop indices) using Check function. Another problem I'm faced with is integrals that evaluates to itself. I mean one expression containing Integrate function evaluates to expression, which also contains Integrate function. Consider this integral for example:

```
Integrate[
Cos[Pi*(a - a0)/(2*Lc)]^2*Cos[m*Pi*(a - a0)/Lc]*
Sin[Pi*(a - a0)/(2*Lc)]/a^2, {a, a0, a0 + Lc}]
```

Usually, no messages is generated for this case and I have no idea how to check for integration success without looking into resulting expression. Looking into every resulting expression is problematic cause I have a lot of them.

Comment: You could set your integral to a variable `i=Integrate[...]` then check the head, `If[Head@i===Integrate,"Handle bad integral","Whatever else."]`. Where you could have this generate a message, or whatever else you need.

Comment: `FreeQ` is also used for this: `FreeQ[expr, Integrate]` returns `False` if `Integrate` evaluated to itself anywhere in the expression `expr`.

Comment: `Check[]`m also may be helpful.

Comment: Allways add as much assumptions as you know. The shown integral can be solved with assuming a0 > 0 && Lc > 0.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Thank you for your comment. But your solution is not time efficient, because it requires reevaluation  of problematic expression. Aren't there a better solution?

Comment: @Akku14 Of course, I'm using assumptions. Here I skipped them for brevity, because they do not make any improvement. The same relates to assumption written by you. They do not allow to solve integral in Mathematica 11.0.1.0

Comment: @Shinrei I don't see why this can't be efficient. You shouldn't reevaluate the expression, just use `i` to store the result of the evaluation the first time you do it, then check if the evaluated expression still has the head `Integrate`, or use`FreeQ` as Michael suggests, then handle it in whatever way you want.

Comment: @N.J.Evans I arrived to conclusion about expression reevaluation, when I have compared time spent for assignment to the variable `i` of above mentioned integral (384 sec.) with time spent for the head check, which you have suggested (389 sec.). It looks like for both inputs Mathematica tries to evaluate integral. The same can be seen for `FreeQ[expr, Integrate]` unless the result was cashed from previous inputs.